# web hosting video files and large files

Tags: hosting, web

I would like to make a website to host videos, and/or large files to a large community of 5000 for example.
What would be the best solution?

Thanks.

Comment: What is your budget?  What is your estimate of the storage and bandwidth requirements?  Is the content public or restricted, and will you need it hosted under a specific legal jurisdiction?

Answer (score 3):

Your probably looking for a content delivery network.  There's several around on the internet.

I've used [EdgeCast](http://www.edgecast.com/) with great success.   [This link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_delivery_network) provides information on CDNs, as well as several free and commercial CDNs.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a simple answer for your question. It depends on what sort of website you are building. Is it a website dedicated to people downloading videos and large files?

If that's the case, you may want to look at Amazon. Their S3 service has some streaming features. I haven't tried that feature yet but it seems like something that you may find useful.